# ExpressJS save api response to file

Tags: node.js, express

I'm having an issue where I cant seem to find a way to save the api response to a local file in json format when a post request is done to /test as seen below. What am I doing wrong? I don't know much about Nodejs, I am simply trying to edit an existing application to save the response to file. Please help.

Many thanks in advance!

```
    const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const axios = require("axios");
const formidable = require('formidable');
const {
   MongoClient
} = require('mongodb');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const FormData = require('form-data');
const multer = require("multer")
require('dotenv').config();

axios.defaults.timeout === 20000;
const app = express();

app.use(cors({
   origin: true
}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());

//mongo
const connectionString = process.env.DB_ENDPOINT || "";
const mongo = new MongoClient(connectionString)
mongo.connect().then(() => {
   console.log('connected mongo!!!!')
})

app.all("*", async (req, res) => {
   const dbConnect = mongo.db();
   upload(req, res, function (e) {

   })
   const formData = new FormData();
   const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

   let data = {}
   let conf = {}
   let response = {
      data: {}
   }
   let statusCode = 200
   const {
      params,
      headers
   } = req;

   const api = axios.create({
      baseURL: process.env.END_POINT,
      headers: {
         authorization: headers.authorization || ""
      }
   })

   form.encoding = 'utf-8';
   await form.parse(req, function (err, fields) {
      data = fields
   });

   // return res.status(200).send({"test":"a"})

try {
      if ((req.path === '/test' || req.path === '/test/') && req.method === 'POST') {
         fs.writeFileSync(`./local/test.json`, JSON.stringify(response));
      } else {
            response = await api.get(req.url, {
               ...data,
               params: params,
               ...req.body
            })
         }
      }
```

Comment: Do you have a directory "local" for your `fs` path? Is your condition true? Try adding `fs.writeFileSync('./test.json', JSON.stringify(response))` and see if that works.

Comment: yes I have the directory there and it writes the file but its blank {} inside it.. the response isnt written in it.

Comment: Oh I see. You've declared the `response` object but you are reassigning the `response` object in the `else` block of the `try catch` block. The `response` variable needs to be updated (reassigned) before it can be used to write the data to a file. The `response` object should hold a value before it can be used here `JSON.stringify(response)`.

Comment: Can u please show me how this would be done? The response should come as the json reply from the api post to /test, sent to the app and saved in test.json

Comment: Try to move the `response = await api.get()` from the `else` code block into the `if` statement before the `fs.writeFileSync`.